# Errors: Errno 2 No such file or directory : Python is not able to find a file that is already present

Tags: python, xml, jupyter, file-read

Here is the code that I wrote to read files in the directory

The code worked fine for the first time but since then it gives the error : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ISS_Ackermann.data.amd'

Code:

```
path = r'C:\Users\Tarun\Desktop\ISS_Ackermann\PlatformLibrary\Package\VehicleDynamicsController\ISS\Feedforward'

# Read every file in directory
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        # Read each line of the file
        for line in f.readlines():
            bs_data = bs_data + line

with io.open("shouldget.xml", "w", encoding='utf-8') as output: 
    output.write(str(bs_data)) 
       
print(bs_data)
```

I have tried the methods given for similar questions but nothing works

Additional info:
IDE: Jupyter
[image]

Comment: Isn't is  ```'ISS_Ackermann.data.pd.amd'```

Comment: @Sujay: sorry for the wrong attachment. It was the screenshot of the attachment I was experimenting with the stuff

Comment: ```with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small modification to your code that should help. This gives an absolute path of where the file is when you try and open it.

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), "r") as f:
        # Read each line of the file
        for line in f.readlines():
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the full path when you call `open`

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
```

should be

```
with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as f:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your notebook is not in the directory where you are looking for the files. Python searches in that directory, ultimately raising an error.

So, use the absolute path of the file

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r"
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approch to debug the situation would be to change the directory to your variable `path`and check what pythons see's there.

```
os.chdir(path)
os.listdir(path)
```

It is possible that you are not in the directory you think you are and this will help you.

After using `os.listdir()` you can get an idea of "where you are" and change the path accordingly to where the file is.

Comment: I get permission error when I implement the "chdir" function